# Denormalizing a subset of normalised dataframe in Python

Tags: python, regression, random-forest

I am new to python and building a random forest model on a set of data. 
My original data contains 33000 rows with 4 columns. I have normalised it using the following formula:

```
normalized_df = (mydata-mydata.mean()) / mydata.std()
```

Now after executing random forest, i have a dataframe which has my predictions, actuals and all the test features (i.e. 9000 rows and 5 columns).
Ive tried to normalize it using the following formula:

```
denorm_df = (normalized_pred_df * mydata.std() ) + mydata.mean()
```

This results in NAN values in most of my columns of the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using StandardScaler from sklearn, and it's invert_transform() function.